# Solve for $a,b,c$ given $1/a + 1/b = 1/c$ and a couple other constraints

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $a, b, c \in \{4, 5, \ldots, 21\}$ and satisfy $1/a + 1/b = 1/c$. Suppose also that $\gcd(b,c)=1$. Find $a, b, c$.

I tried this problem and I got the answer,
but I can't to understand how $\gcd(b-c,c^2)=\gcd(b,c)$. when gcd(b,c)=1

My attempt:
From question we can see that $b > c$. On
simplifying, we get $$a = c + \frac{c^2}{b-c}.$$

Comment: It is not generally true that $\gcd (b-c,c^2)=\gcd (b,c)$.  Take $b=10, c=2$. Since you do not provide your reasoning, we cannot see why this is important.

Comment: I think $\gcd(b - c, c^2) = gcd(b,c)$ holds with the added constraint that $\gcd(b,c) = 1$.

Comment: Assume a prime $p$ divides $b - c$ and $c^2$. Then it must divide $b$ and $c$. Similarly, for the reverse direction.

Comment: Rather, $\gcd(b,c) \mid \gcd(b-c,c^2)$

Comment: theakholic... can you please explain how gcd(b−c,c^2)=gcd(b,c) when gcd(b,c)=1 and from here how can we judge that b-c = 1 please explain me

Comment: Well, if $(a,b,c)$ is a solution, then $a,b,c$ must be integers. So in particular, $a - c$ should be an integer. What have you calculated $a - c$ to be? Work with that.

Comment: You must use the fact that $4 \le a,b,c \le 21$.  Otherwise, we can double all of them and have another solution.  Everything you have said so far ignores that.

Comment: gcd (b,c) and gcd (b-c,c^2) will have the same prime divisors but not nescessarily the same powers.  But if gcd(c,b) =1 then gcd (b,c)=gcd (b-c,c)=gcd(b-c,c^2)

Comment: Let p be a prime number that divides both c^2 and b-c.  p divides c^2 so p divides c.  As p divides b-c and c, p divides b=b-c+c.  So p divides both b and c.  But gcd (b,c)=1 so there is no such prime number.  So gcd (b-c,c^2)=1.

Comment: So b-c =1.  So a>=4^2+4=20.  But a < 5+5^2=30.  So a =20, c=4 so b=5.

Comment: You can also simplify to a=bc/(b-c) if that's any eadier.  Any factor of b-c must be a factor of b or c which means it must be a factor of both.  But gcd = 1 so there is no factor of b-c so b-c =1 etc.

Comment: Your answer doesn't help.  Gcd (b,c)=1 so you have 1 divides x2 which doesn't help.  b-c must divide c^2.  So any prime factor of b-c must be a prime factor of c.  If it's a prime factor of and it is a prime factor of b-c it must also be a prime factor of b.  So it is a prime factor of b and c.  But gcd (b,c)=1 so there is no prime factor.  So b-c has no prime factors.  only 1 and -1 have no prime factors.  So b-c =1.

Comment: Roby5.  Are you aware that if a|b and a|c then a|mb+/-nc?  And that if prime p|c^2 then p|c. And if a|b and b|c then a|c? If so c^2/(b-c) being a whole number means (b-c)|c^2 so any prime p|b-c means p|c^2 means p|c means p|b means p|gcd (b-c)=1 means p=1 except 1 is technically not prime so prime p|b-c is impossible.  So b-c has no prime divisors.  So b-c =1.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously $b>c$. Multiply both sides by $abc$ to get$$bc+ac=ab$$It follows immediately that$$a=\frac{bc}{b-c}=\frac{bc-c^2+c^2}{b-c}=c+\frac{c^2}{b-c}$$So $b-c|c^2$, but $\gcd(b-c, c^2)=1$ since $\gcd(b, c)=1$. Hence we must have $b-c=1$, which in turn gives $a=c+c^2$.

From $c+c^2=a<22$ one gets $c<5$, so $c=4$ and thus the only solutions is$$(a, b, c)=(c+c^2, c+1, c)$$Where $c=4$.

Comment: please please tell me from scratch...   i have lots of doubts
1.how b>c
2.what is this b-cIc^2
3.how gcd(b-c,c^2)=gcd(b,c)
4.how b-c = 1

Answer (score 0):

Then equation:

$$XY+XZ+YZ=N$$

If we ask what ever number: $p$

That the following sum can always be factored: $p^2+N=ks$

Solutions can be written.

$$X=p$$

$$Y=s-p$$

$$Z=k-p$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ prime $p|(b-c)$ and $p|c^2$. From $p|c^2$ we get $p|c$ then $p|b$ because $b=(b-c) + c$.

Now let $p$ prime $p|b, p|c$. It follows that $p|(b-c), p|c^2$.

The conclusion is $\gcd(b,c)$ and $\gcd(b-c,c^2)$ have the same prime divisors. From here we deduce if one of them is $1$ the other one is also $1$.

Back to your problem. Because $\gcd(b,c)=1$, we have $\gcd(b-c,c^2)=1$

But $$a = c + \frac{c^2}{b-c} \tag1$$ therefore $(b-c)|c^2$. It follows that $b-c=1$ (otherwise, if $b-c \ge2$ then there is a prime $p | b-c$ and because $(b-c)|c^2$ we get $\gcd(b-c,c^2) \ne 1$ false).

Now we'll find all the coprime pairs ($c,b=c+1$) where $c \in \{4, 5, \ldots, 20\}$ satisfying (1).

We get
$
c=4, b=5, a=20
$ as unique solution. There is no reason to check for $c \ge 5$ because $c^2 \ge 25$ implies $a \gt 25$, which is false.

Answer (score 0):

$1/a + 1/b = 1/c$ so

$1/a =1/c - 1/b$ so

$a = 1/[1/c-1/b] = bc/(b-c)$

As this is a whole number $b-c$ divides $bc.$ So any factor of $b-c$ must be a factor of either $b$ or $c.$  If it's a factor of $b$ and also $b-c$ it is a factor of $c$ as well.  If is a factor of $c$ and also $b-c$ then it is also a factor of $b.$ Either way, any factor of $b-c$ is a factor of both $b$ and $c.$

But $\gcd(b,c)=1$ so $1$ is the only factor of $b-c.$ So $b-c = \pm 1$ and as $a,b,c$ are positive $b-c=1.$

So $a=bc$ so $a\geq 4\times 5=20.$ $ a\leq 21$ and $21$ is clearly not an option. $(21=3x7 != bc$ where $b-c=1)$

So $a=20, b,c=4,5.$ $ b-c=1 $ so $b=c+1$ so $b=5$ and $c=4.$

Answer (score -1):

As you say, $a,b \gt c$.  Presumably you demand $a \neq b$ or there would be many solutions with $a=b=c/2$.  We can demand $a \gt b$ and just try values for $b-c$.  If $b-c=1$, we have $a=c+c^2$ and the only value in range is $c=4, a=20, b=5$.  If $b-c=2,$ we must have $c$ even and $a=c+c^2/2$, which works with $c=4, a=12, b=6$, but $c=6$ makes $a$ too large.  $b-c=3$ gives $a=c+c^2/3$ and gives $c=6, b=9, a=18$.  $b-c=4$ fails because it either gives $c=4, a=8, b=8$ or $c=8, a=24$.  All higher $b-c$ also fail (you need to prove this), so we have three solutions.

Comment: Can you list the three solutions?

Comment: @EugenCovaci:   They are in the text.  $(20,5,4), (12,6,4), (18,9,6)$

Comment: $\gcd(b,c)=1$ so the last two are not solutions

Comment: @EugenCovaci:  the original problem did not have the restriction that $\gcd (b,c)=1$.  Originally OP asked how to prove that, hence my first comment.